# Is Android checkbox attribute "android:button" supported in Android4.0?

Tags: android

I'm testing Checkbox's attribute  android:button  in xml file. New style works well in Android6.0 ,but still displays the default style in Android4.0. 
I check StateListDrawable Added in API level 1. Why this attribute can't work in Android4.0.

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
```

or

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/state_list_xml"/>
```

Both ways have the same result as I describe above.

Comment: mipmap directory was added only in 4.2, can you try to use image from drawable directory?

Comment: @Bracadabra the 2nd way using drawable xml and image still can't in 4.0